# SQLite Data Provider is missing in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core

Using `Nuget Package Manager` I installed `System.Data.SQLite (x86/x64)` in `VS2017`. That resulted in installing the following packages as well:

```
System.Data.SQLite
System.Data.SQLite.EF6
System.Data.SQLite.Core
```

But as shown in image below, the `Add New Data Source` dialog box does not show the `SQLite Data Provider`:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The NuGet package is for your project and does not include a provider. For that, you need to install a DDEX provider package. There doesn't seem to be an official SQLite DDEX provider package for Visual Studio 2017, but you can try one of these two unofficial ones:

[SQLite / SQL Server Compact Toolbox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.SQLServerCompactSQLiteToolbox) by 
ErikEJ

[dotConnect ADO.NET Data Provider for SQLite](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DevartSoftware.dotConnectADONETDataProviderforSQLite) by 
Devart Software

Comment: But as demoed [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/danielggarcia/archive/2013/12/22/portable-databases-ii-using-sqlite-with-entity-framework.aspx) one should be able to use `SQLite Data Provider` in `Add New Data Source` wizard once you install `System.Data.SQLite (x86/x64)` using `Nuget Package Manager`. What could be missing here?

Comment: It's not clear what version of VS that post was about, but considering that it was posted in 2013, perhaps it was for VS2012. Things have changed a lot in VS2017, so don't look at posts for other versions and think it will work the same for VS2017. If it were as simple as installing the NuGet package, ErikEJ and Devart wouldn't have wasted their time creating providers. There was a request for an official provider, but the request has been closed with no provider. You probably can reopen it or create a new request.

Comment: I have some additional advice here: https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/EF6-workflow-with-SQLite-DDEX-provider

Comment: @RacilHilan Thank you for answering my question: "What could be missing here?" and clearing my confusion.

Comment: @ErikEJ Your [link](https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/EF6-workflow-with-SQLite-DDEX-provider) further cleared my confusion on why we need a third party tool here for my case of VS2017 and EF. Thank you.

Comment: Note that neither of those tools support DataSets.

Comment: @ErikEJ your link, to own toolbox, clearly shows that "some" `System.Data.Sqlite Database File` should appear. But after following the instructions only an "SQLite Provider (Simple for EF6 by ErikEJ)" is added which, of course, cannot be used as "Data Source" (about which is the question - `Add New Data Source`).