# SQLITE Connection not appearing in VS2017

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net

I have the same problem as:
[SQLite connection not appearing for VS2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139799/sqlite-connection-not-appearing-for-vs2015)
the **difference** is, that i use **Visual Studio 2017** [here's an image of the connections availabe in my Visual Studio 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRSCg.png)

I have downloaded and installed a lot of packages from: 
https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki
but none of these packages makes this option available in my server explorer.

I have downloaded and installed `System.Data.SQLite` nuget and `ado.net`, but the results were the same,one weird thing though was that when i was installing `ado.net`,  the design-time support for the environment showed a blank box [here's an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHqpk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was raised in the discussion (was having the same issue)
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036387/sqlite-data-provider-is-missing-in-visual-studio-2017)